# search sequence in genome with mismatches

Tags: python, perl, awk, biopython, bioperl

i have a fastq file with more than 100 million reads in it and a genome sequence of 10000 in length

i want to take out the sequences from the fastq file and search in the genome sequence with allowing 3 mismatches

I tried in this way using awk i got the sequences from fastq file:

1.fq(few lines)

> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1101:1207:2171 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>   NATCCCCATCCTCTGCTTGCTTTTCGGGATATGTTGTAGGATTCTCAGC
>
> +
>
> 1=ADBDDHD;F>GF@FFEFGGGIAEEI?D9DDHHIGAAF:BG39?BB
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1101:1095:2217 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>   TAGGATTTCAAATGGGTCGAGGTGGTCCGTTAGGTATAGGGGCAACAGG
>
> +
>
> ??AABDD4C:DDDI+C:C3@:C):1?*):?)?################
>
> $ awk 'NR%4==2' 1.fq
>
> NATCCCCATCCTCTGCTTGCTTTTCGGGATATGTTGTAGGATTCTCAGC
>   TAGGATTTCAAATGGGTCGAGGTGGTCCGTTAGGTATAGGGGCAACAGG

i have all the sequences in file,now i want to take each line of sequence and search in genome sequence with allowing 3 mismatches and if it finds print the sequences

example:

genome sequence file:

> GGGGAGGAATATGATTTACAGTTTATTTTTCAACTGTGCAAAATAACCTTAACTGCAGACGTTATGACATACATACATTCTATGAATTCCACTATTTTGGAGGACTGGAATTTTGGTCTACAACCTCCCCCAGGAGGCACACTAGAAGATACTTATAGGTTTGTAACCCAGGCAATTGCTTGTCAAAAACATACA

search sequence file:

> GGGGAGGAATATGAT
>
> GGGGAGGAATATGAA
>
> GGGGAGGAATATGCC
>
> TCAAAAACATAGG
>
> TCAAAAACATGGG

OUTPUT FILE:

> GGGGAGGAATATGAT 0 # 0 mismatch exact sequence
>
> GGGGAGGAATATGAA 1 # 1 mismatch
>
> GGGGAGGAATATGCC 2 # 2 mismatch
>
> TCAAAAACATAGG   2 # 2 mismatch
>
> TCAAAAACATGGG   3 # 3 mismatch

Comment: how many search sequences (and are the example lengths you show representative?)

Comment: that just an example to show it maps any where in the sequence(with allowing mismatches).there is approximate length of sequences in my actual file(from 25 to 100) @ysth

Comment: my file of search sequences contain more than 100 million lines which did extract them using awk from fastq file(shown above) @ysth

Comment: just to make sure I understand...you want to search for 100000000 sequences of length 25-100 in a single genome sequence of length about 10000?

Comment: yes,that what i am looking for..take each line one by one and search in genome sequence with mismatches @ysth

Comment: i was doing in this way but it is matching at the beggining of genome sequence import re
seq="TTCCTATAAAGTATCAGGATTACAATACAGGGTATTTAGAATACATTTACCTGACCCCAATAAGTTTGGTTTTCCGGGCCTGTGTAGGTGTTGAGGTAGGTCGTGGTCAGCCATTAGGTGTGGGCATTAGTGGCCATCCTTTATTAAATAAATTGGATGACACAGAAAATGCTAGTGCTTATGCAGCAAATGCAGGTGTGGATAATAGAGAATGTATATCTATGGATTACAAACAAACACAAT"
with open("a.fq") as f:
    for line in f:
            line=line.strip()
            line = re.search(r'line',seq)
            mismatches=sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(seq,line))
            if mismatches<=3:
                print line,mismatches @ysth

Comment: i want to do search the whole sequence @ysth

Answer (score 2):

something like?

```
use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::Approx qw(aslice);
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $genseq = "gseq.txt"; #the long sequence

$_ = read_file($genseq);

#read small patterns from stdin
while(my $patt = <>) {
    chomp $patt;
    my $len = length($patt);
    my($index, $size, $distance) = aslice($patt, ["3D0S3", "minimal_distance"]);
    say "$patt matched approx. at $index with mismatch $distance" if $distance <= 3;
}
```

for you input produces:

```
GGGGAGGAATATGAT matched approx. at 0 with mismatch 0
GGGGAGGAATATGAA matched approx. at 0 with mismatch 1
GGGGAGGAATATGCC matched approx. at 0 with mismatch 2
TCAAAAACATAGG matched approx. at 179 with mismatch 2
TCAAAAACATGGG matched approx. at 179 with mismatch 3
```

Honestly, haven't idea how will work with an 10000 chars long genseq...

Comment: thank you @jm666 i am using BOWTIE to map the sequences now.let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using an alignment tool designed for this data for a couple of reasons:

- Those tools will also find reverse complemented matches (though, you could also implement this).
- Aligners will properly handle paired-end reads and multiple matches.
- Most aligners are written in C and use data structures and algorithms designed for this amount of data.

For those reasons, and others, any script you come up with will likely not be near as fast and complete as the tools that already exist. If you want to specify the number of mismatches to keep, instead of aligning all your reads and then parsing the output, you could use Vmatch if you have access to it (this tool is very fast and good for many matching tasks).